# What's the best way to checkout from TFS to eclipse using TEE?

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-cdt, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm developing a QNX app (thus I'm using an old version of Eclipse-CDT C++ etc.). Up until now I've been checking out with TFS and then importing the project files to the workspace via Import->General->ExistingProject; this means I can build/debug etc, but I've only had TFS functionality available via TeamExplorer from the TFS perspective. If I import the same projects to a different workspace via Import->Team->TFS then I have extra TEE functionality but I can't build/debug etc.

So, what's the recommended way to do this? I'd like both functionalities.

**Edit** ---
I imported each project one-at-a-time via Import->Team->TFS and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why importing from TFS doesn't detect that project's nature correctly.  (Are you not checking in `.project` files?  Are you using Maven?)

Regardless, if you want to go the route of importing an existing project from disk, just go to the Team menu, select Share, then select TFS.  It should detect your working folder mappings and simply set TFS as the source control provider for that project, which should give you all the TFS bindings from within editors and views.

Comment: Thanks. In the repository, we've got .project, .cproject and .cdtproject files. We're not using Maven (using teambuild?). Just to reiterate, Since my stuff's already in TFS, I should be able to create a new workspace and then import>Team>TFS and start coding?