# Automatic checkouts of Mathematica files from Eclipse TFS

Tags: tfs, eclipse-plugin, wolfram-mathematica, team-explorer-everywhere, vcs-checkout

The TFS add-in for Eclipse **doesn't automatically check out files when you edit them**, and you get this annoying and misleading error message when you go to save:

[image]

> Mathematica could not write some data to the file
>   C:\Dev\ProjectName\Main\Mathematica\ExcelImport.nb. You should check
>   that file's permissions.

I've looked up a couple of threads:

http://team-foundation-server.blogspot.com.au/2007/06/automatic-checkouts-with-team-explorer.html

[TEE 2012 does not check out files automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837803/tee-2012-does-not-check-out-files-automatically)

[what's the best way to checkout from TFS to eclipse using TEE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590153/whats-the-best-way-to-checkout-from-tfs-to-eclipse-using-tee)

But in my case we're using it for Mathematica projects and they have `the Team menu` but they do **not** have the `select Share, then select TFS`

Hopefully someone out there knows a workaround, we are using Juno with TFS2010 (cough @EdwardThomson)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TFS 2012 you can create a [local workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155781.aspx#local) rather then a server workspace.

Local workspaces work in a similar way to SVN and there is no need to check out files to edit them

Comment: Thanks James I'll `check it out` on monday.